# BUG] Segmentation fault at 0xffffffffffffff8c ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, cocoapods, podspec

M1 Chip Macbook Pro produced this error after `pod install`. Can anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0013 p:---- s:0067 e:000066 CFUNC  :multi_perform
c:0012 p:0016 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/multi/operations.rb:212
c:0011 p:0028 s:0055 e:000054 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/multi/operations.rb:201
c:0010 p:0038 s:0049 e:000048 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/multi/operations.rb:50
c:0009 p:0012 s:0044 e:000043 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/hydra/runnable.rb:15
c:0008 p:0005 s:0040 e:000039 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/hydra/memoizable.rb:51 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:0009 s:0036 e:000034 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352
c:0006 p:0042 s:0027 e:000026 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0021 e:000020 CFUNC  :loop
c:0004 p:0006 s:0017 e:000016 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0014 e:000013 CFUNC  :catch
c:0002 p:0008 s:0009 e:000008 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:---- s:0003 e:000002 (none) [FINISH]
```

I just tried to install the pods as usual. This time it gives me the error above

Answer (score 0):

`ethon` is a wrapper around libcurl. If you have updated curl (e.g. with a `brew upgrade`), its binary programing interface may have changed from when you originally compiled ethon.

To resolve this, you could try to uninstall your existing ethon gem with

```bash
gem uninstall ethon
```

and re-install it as part of your `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I uninstalled and then installed it again. However, still the same error only difference is ethon version is 0.16.0